# How to swap 2 vertices to fix a twisted face?

Tags: vertices, faces

I've got some weird geometry where some faces got twisted and the only solution I know is to swap the vertices. Is there any easy way to swap vertices? [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/km5ce2/ways_to_flatten_twisted_faces/) they claim [`LoopTools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html) > *Flatten* would do the trick but it does not work for me in Blender 3.3.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply select those two vertices, press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to invert the vertices by scaling with -1 on all axes. No orientation needed. Of course this also works in *Edge Select* mode, then you just have to select one edge instead of two vertices.

Comment: oh yes of course

Comment: awesome! even better thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Select the *Normal* orientation and rotate 180° on X?

[image]

Comment: hey thanks! that's a tricky one! I would need to add a custom orientation for every face I try to twist?

Comment: actually selecting the Normal option should work

Comment: cool thank you!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Too complicated ;) Look at my answer.